# using a word for another meaning

Tags: word-choice, legal, videogame, english

Sorry if it sounds stupid but here's the question:

I have a character who thinks the Italian word "pronto" has a similar meaning as "stupid" no matter how much others tell him the meaning of it is "quickly".(the character speaks English by the way)

So I just wanted to know if I can do this or not. More clearly, I want to know if there is something like a law to stop me from doing this or not.

Comment: reminds me of "Don't say Si, say Oui." https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gExpWXHh5-Y

Comment: I mean, it's a misunderstanding a character has. Why do you believe it could possibly be illegal for you to write?

Comment: @WeckarE. I just wanted to make sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.

As regards legality, that depends on which country your game or text is published in. It would be legal in the vast majority of countries, but there are a few countries with vague and overreaching laws on public morality and censorship that would apply even to fiction.

Practically speaking, you don't have to worry.

Comment: thanks for answer